# Call a method on getattr() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use `python-metar` to decode [METAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) data. Object returned after parsing METAR strings looks like this:

```
>>> dir(decoded)[-5:]
['wind_shift', 'wind_shift_time', 'wind_speed', 'wind_speed_peak', 'windshear']
```

These attributes, have additional methods - `value()`, `unit()`, and `string()`.
I used  the `getattr()` builtin function to loop over all of them:

```
>>> attributes = [..., 'wind_speed', 'wind_speed_peak', 'windshear']
>>> for attr in attributes:
>>>    print(getattr(decoded, attr))
```

But this way I get the default string representation, and that is a string with a value and its unit, like `10 knots`, while I'd like to get just the numerical value, which I can reach through `value()` method:

```
>>> decoded.wind_speed.value()
10.0
```

So I can't figure how to use `getattr()` and at the same time to call a method (in this case `value()` method).

Comment: Please try this `print(getattr(getattr(decoded, attr), "value")()`

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly!

Comment: I added same in answer. Please select it as answer. that help other to get exact answer for same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your code, `getattr` will return till `decoded.wind_speed`. If you want to call `value` function of `decoded.wind_speed` you have to call `value()` with the object return by `getattr`.

```
print(getattr(decoded, attr).value())
```

**OR**

You can use another `getattr` to call `value` method.

```
print(getattr(getattr(decoded, attr)), "value")()
```